# Angular: Provide Injection token to a module imported in a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am having issues in providing injection tokens to a module that I import in a lazy loaded module.
In the module, I defined a `withConfig` static function to set configuration:

```
  static withConfig(
    config: Config
  ): ModuleWithProviders<MySubModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: MySubModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SUBS_MANAGER,
          useExisting: config.subsManager,
        },
        {
          provide: QUERY_SERVICE,
          useExisting: config.dataApi,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
```

`subsManager`and `dataApi` are both services:

```
export const QUERY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<Type<any>>('QueryService');
export const SUBS_MANAGER = new InjectionToken<SubscriptionManager>(
  'SubscriptionManagerService'
);
```

This is what I do in my lazy-loaded module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //all my other modules
    MySubModule.withConfig({
      dataApi: APIService,
      subsManager: SubscriptionManagerService,
    }),
   providers: [
     APIService,
     SubscriptionManagerService,
  ],
```

But I get this error:

```
R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken SubscriptionManagerService -> InjectionToken SubscriptionManagerService -> InjectionToken SubscriptionManagerService]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken SubscriptionManagerService!
```

How can I correctly set tokens for this module?

Comment: can you reproduce this demo in stackblitz ?

Comment: as per error, You need to provide `SubscriptionManagerService` inside app.module.ts providers array.